# Octave's packages from previous installation

Tags: installation, octave

I just downloaded and built octave 4.0 from their website. There are a lot of packages already installed from the 3.6 version. I was wondering if is it possible to transfer that installation so that octave 4.0 would recognize them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read the help text for pkg and search for the word update. You can't transfer the install because oct files will need to be rebuild from source to link to the new octave version.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually very helpful. I tried to download the packages but sourceforge has been a real trouble lately.